# FineUploader Set a parameter to pass as a "constant" parameter to each subsequent upload after the first successful upload

Tags: jquery, file, callback, uploader, fine-uploader

I am using the jQuery version of the Fineuploader script (ver 3.3).

I have created the necessary upload script and all appears to be working as expected, but my goal here is to upload multiple files to a single folder which is dynamically created based on the database entry ID which gets created when the first file uploads. To do this, I have set up the folder/db entry ID as a return paramater with the JSON info I return at the end of my script and then, using the on('complete'...) function, I am attempting to set that parameter to pass back to my PHP script in order to prevent my PHP script from creating a new DB entry, thus creating a new folder for each file.

On logging the results in my JS console I see that this is not working because it appears my use of on('complete'...) only sets the parameter after the last file is finished uploading. I have tried to look at the other callbacks detailed on http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html but haven't found one that makes use of the JSON response from my PHP script.

Is there a way I can set this parameter on the first successful upload, and keep it constant for each subsequent upload in a particular batch of file uploads?

Here is the JS I am currently using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var folderID;

    jQuery('#file_multi_upload').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '/filehandler'
        },
        debug: true
    }).on('complete', function(event, id, name, responseJSON){
        window.folderID = responseJSON['folder_id'];
        var uploadedFilePath = responseJSON['filepath'];
        var oldVal = jQuery('#uploaded_files').val();

        if (oldVal != '') {
            jQuery('#uploaded_files').val(oldVal+" "+ uploadedFilePath);
        } else {
            jQuery('#uploaded_files').val(uploadedFilePath);
        }
    }).on('upload', function(event, id, filename){
        jQuery(this).fineUploader('setParams', { 'uploadFolderId': folderID });
    });
});
```

And here is the my PHP uploader script:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: File Upload Handler
 */

global $wpdb;

$result = array(
'success' => false
);

if (!empty($_FILES) && is_array($_FILES)) :

if (!isset($_POST['uploadFolderId']) || $_POST['uploadFolderId'] !== '') :

$uploadData = array(
    'uploaded' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$wpdb->insert('wp_fileuploads_rel', $uploadData);

$uploadDbEntryId = $wpdb->insert_id;

else :

$uploadDbEntryId = $_POST['uploadFolderId'];

endif;

$targetPath = ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/competition_uploads/'.$uploadDbEntryId.'/';

if (!is_dir($targetPath)) {
mkdir($targetPath);
}

foreach ($_FILES as $file) :

$filePath = $targetPath . basename( $file['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filePath)) :

    $insertData = array(
    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'filename' => $file['name'],
    'filepath' => $filePath,
    'upload_id' => $uploadDbEntryId
    );

    if ($wpdb->insert('wp_fileuploads', $insertData)) :

    $serverPath = ABSPATH;
    $siteUrl = get_site_url();

    $fileUrl = str_replace($serverPath, $siteUrl .'/', $filePath);

    $result = array(
        'success' => true,
        'filepath' => $fileUrl,
        'folder_id' => $uploadDbEntryId,
        'the_request' => $_POST
    );
    endif;
    //$wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null );

//      echo "The file ".  basename( $file['tmp_name']['name'])." has been uploaded";
endif;

endforeach;

endif;

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a hook that allows you to know when a batch is done.  Anyway, what if a user forgets a file and uploads another batch?  If I understand correctly, you would have two folders, then.  You should give the user a button to say "I am done uploading".  Then you could move the files to the destination folder when that happens.